# Graphite Docker not publishing Dashboard

Tags: graphite

Following [this link](https://github.com/graphite-project/docker-graphite-statsd) I installed graphite with docker.
Now I should be able to find graphite on `localhost/dashboard`
But there's nothing. What I'm missing? Looked quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

When [running docker on macOS](https://medium.com/@yutafujii_59175/a-complete-one-by-one-guide-to-install-docker-on-your-mac-os-using-homebrew-e818eb4cfc3) you need to use `docker-machine`,
That sets the docker IP to `export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"`

So to access the dashboard you need to type `http://192.168.99.100/dashboard`